Jupyter notebook nbconvert ignore hyperlink in header
I've generated report from Jupyter notebook using nbconvert and I got this hyperlink (¶)

Does anyone know how to remove this one from the generated html?

What is 'PV by platform'? What do any of the URLs or links say? This doesn't look standard and so you have to tell us more. Where are you using Jupyter and how did you install it? Are you on your own computer having installed it with Anaconda?

Use "--HTMLExporter.anchor_link_text=' '" option on nbconvert: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html
